# Install Ubuntu alongside Mac OS X option only gives me a few 30 Gigs

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, mac

I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside Mac and I have 1 TB of memory. I inserted the install CD, selected a language, and did all that other stuff. When i clicked the "Install Ubuntu alongside Mac OS X" option then clicked "Install now" it went to the screen where you size how much memory you want the two operating systems to share. But it only gave me about 30 Gigs to size from. I want one to have 500 Gigs and the other to have the rest.

Comment: Is your hard drive already partitioned? I can't remember what the install screen looks like exactly, but is there an "advanced" option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to create the partitions with the Disk Utility of OSX. After that you can install Ubuntu on the previously created Partition.